# How to sum numbers with arrays in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sum

I have this array:

```
a = [15, 8.5, 19, 20, 5.5, 12.49, 17]
```

I want to sum the numeric values greater than 10

Comment: [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-select) the greater than 10 then [`sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-sum) them.

Comment: I don't know how this question could be more clear. Would the disapprover care to provide a justification for the downvote and vote to close? Note that the asker is evidently new to Ruby.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: "I want to do X" is a wish, not a problem statement. It is unclear what the problem is. Does the OP get an error? If yes, what is the error? Does the OP get an undesired result? If yes, what is the undesired result? And so on.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, is it not a reasonable assumption that the OP would have given at least a minimal explanation of their attempted solution if they were really asking why they got an error or why their answer was incorrect?

Comment: I understand the downvote, which is for lack of research/effort, but it's certainly not close-worthy (unless someone knows of a duplicate somewhere).

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [15, 8.5, 19, 20, 5.5, 12.49, 17]
```

```
a.sum { |n| n > 10 ? n : 0 }
  #=> 83.49
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Cary's answer.

```
a = [15, 8.5, 19, 20, 5.5, 12.49, 17] 

a.select { |n| n > 10 }.sum
#=> 83.49
```

Cary's solution is probably a bit faster.

Answer (score -1):

```
array.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x }
```

or see https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum

Comment: The documentation link is wrong. As the question isn't tagged with Rails, and you're not using the `sum` method.